# mysql multiple conditions on the same column

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, boolean-logic, having

I have a table which, saves the subscriptions of users and guests to topic_names.

[image]

Here's the example, now I need to support a bunch of complex queries for example, `get all the users who are subscribed to 'so' and 'all' or are subscribed to 'so2'` in short : `so && (all || so2)` I first tried doing it via `having clause`, but looks like the same column doesn't work in that case, so I came up with this:

```sql
select *
from `wp_push_notification_topics`
where exists(select *
             from `wp_push_notification_topics` as `wp_laravel_reserved_0`
             where `wp_push_notification_topics`.`user_id` = `wp_laravel_reserved_0`.`user_id`
               and `topic_name` = 'so'
               and exists(select *
                          from `wp_push_notification_topics`
                          where `wp_laravel_reserved_0`.`user_id` = `wp_push_notification_topics`.`user_id`
                            and `topic_name` = 'all'
                            or exists(select *
                                       from `wp_push_notification_topics` as `wp_laravel_reserved_1`
                                       where `wp_push_notification_topics`.`user_id` = `wp_laravel_reserved_1`.`user_id`
                                         and `topic_name` = 'so2')))
```

Which works fine.

[image]

But even if I change:

```sql
and `topic_name` = 'all'
```

to

```sql
and `topic_name` = 'all22'
```

I get this result:

[image]

Which is clearly the exact as the previous result and therefore wrong! user_id 2 row's must not be included, which means I'm doing something wrong, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `user_id`s with aggregation if you set correctly the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM wp_push_notification_topics
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(topic_name = 'so') > 0 AND SUM(topic_name IN ('all', 'so2')) > 0;
```

If you want to restrict the conditions so that the user is not subscribed to any other than 'so', 'all' and 'so2' you can add to the `HAVING` clause:

```
AND  SUM(topic_name NOT IN ('so', 'all', 'so2')) = 0
```

If you want all the rows of the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_push_notification_topics
WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM wp_push_notification_topics
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING SUM(topic_name = 'so') > 0 AND SUM(topic_name IN ('all', 'so2')) > 0
);
```

Comment: This is great never had seen sum being used for this purpose thank you one simple problem however, on a more complex example : `so && (all || so2 && (something || something_else))` is there any way to also support this more complex query? (I'm looking for a general solution with nested support not for a specific example's solution)

Comment: @stevemoretz you can set the conditions anyway that you want if you use properly the boolean operators. Your example is not clear because the AND operator has higher precedence than the OR operator. You could do something like: `HAVING SUM(topic_name = 'so') > 0 AND SUM(topic_name IN ('all', 'so2')) > 0 AND SUM(topic_name IN (something, something_else)) > 0` or `HAVING SUM(topic_name = 'so') > 0 AND (SUM(topic_name IN ('all', 'so2')) > 0 OR SUM(topic_name IN (something, something_else)) > 0)`

Comment: That's it I was using the wrong syntax thank you so much!